# Prevent method execution and property and variable access/modification

Tags: c#, postsharp, modularity, aop

I am unexperienced with Aspect-Oriented Programming.  However, I've read a fair amount of PDFs and documentation available from PostSharp, and I think that I understand the gist of the paradigm.  I have a pretty unique problem, and I believe AOP can be used to solve it.  My predicament is as follows:

Many classes will inherit from `A`, which can be `enabled` or `disabled`.  Consider `B`, which `extends A`.  If `B` is `disabled`, I would like all method execution and property and variable access/modification to be disabled.  That is, `B.ExecuteMethod();` and `B.Property = newValue;` will have no effect if `B` is disabled. Furthermore, if one expects a return value, the value will be defaulted to `0` or `null` if `B` is `disabled`.  That is, I would like to have expected default values for objects and values.

I am using the PostSharp C# library, which seems *very* powerful and well-developed.  I believe my problem can be solved by means of `AttributeInheritance`.  For example, `A` can be defined as:

```
[ModularAttribute(AttributeInheritance = MulticastInheritance.Multicast)]
public class A {

    private bool m_enabled;

    public A(){
        m_enabled = true;
    }

    public bool Enabled() {
        get {
            return m_enabled;
        }
        set {
            m_enabled = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and `B` can `extend A`.  Moreover, my attribute, `ModularAttribute` can be defined as:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class ModularAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect {

    public ModularAttribute() {
    }

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args) {
        // only execute code if enabled
    }
}
```

This attribute will be applied to `B` because `B extends A`.

The root of my problem is: I need `ModularAttribute` to reference `A`'s `Enabled` property, such that `OnEntry` will only execute code if `Enabled` is true.  Since this is a class-level aspect, I cannot parameterize a wrapped version of `m_enabled` to `ModularAttribute` since it is out of scope.

Is there a way that I can tell `ModularAttribute` that all of its owners will `implement` a specific `interface`?  If so, could `ModularAttribute` access the specific properties from said `interface`?  If so, this would solve my problem.

To clarify, I would like to "tell" PostSharp: "The `class` that uses `ModularAttribute` is guaranteed to `implement C`.  So, let `ModularAttribute` access whatever `C` defines because it's ensured to work."

`C` can be defined as:

```
public interface C { 
    public bool Enabled();
}
```

Thus, in `ModularAttribute`, I could do something along the lines of

```
if (attachedClass.Enabled == false) { 
    // don't execute code
} else {
    // execute code
}
```

This problem can be perceived as authentication on the per-object level rather than the more typical per-user level.  Having to add an `if, else` check on every `Property` and `Method` that `extends A` seems like a cross-cutting concern.  Thus, I think AOP is a fitting choice for this problem; however, because of my inexperience with this paradigm, I might be approaching it the wrong way.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.  Thanks for the help,

Comment: Hi, i want to clarify some doubt. Why don't you use [Transaction(AttributeInheritance=MulticastInheritance.MultiCast)] or is it because Modular Attribute is a method- level aspect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little concerned that this much inheritance could be a design flaw or at least a huge maintenance headache, but assuming that it's not, let's soldier on...

I don't think there's a way to do exactly what you want to do. Even if PostSharp had the ability, C# needs to know the type at compile time (before PostSharp even touches it).

I suggest that you use CompileTimeValidate to verify that the class the aspect is used on is of a certain type, and once that's in place, you can cast `args.Instance` to your interface type without worrying about an invalid cast exception. And if that class *doesn't* implement `IEnabled`, then you'll get a compile-time error.

Here's a quick example:

```
public interface IEnabled
{
    bool Enabled { get; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ModularAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override bool CompileTimeValidate(System.Reflection.MethodBase method)
    {
        if(typeof(IEnabled).IsAssignableFrom(method.DeclaringType))
            return true;
        Message.Write(method, SeverityType.Error, "MYERR001", "Aspect can't be used on a class that doesn't implement IEnabled");
        return false;
    }

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var obj = (IEnabled) args.Instance; // this will always be a safe cast
        if(!obj.Enabled)
            args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
    }
}
```

There's a catch though: you don't want this aspect being used on the Enabled property itself, because that would cause a stack overflow (i.e. the aspect checks the property, causing the aspect to check the property, etc). So make sure to *exclude* `Enabled` using `AttributeExclude`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new B();
        b.Enabled = false;
        b.SomeMethod();
        b.AnotherMethod();
    }
}

public interface IEnabled
{
    bool Enabled { get; }
}

[Modular(AttributeInheritance = MulticastInheritance.Multicast)]
public class A : IEnabled
{
    [Modular(AttributeExclude = true)]
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in SomeMethod");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public void AnotherMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in AnotherMethod");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your help!  I will let you know if your advice solves the issue, or if I run into further problems.  Again, thank you for the help -- it is much appreciated.

Comment: Your solution worked phenomenally.  Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: For those wondering, I applied a second `Attribute`, `SecondAttribute : LocationInterceptionAspect` to `A` such that it that prevents `property` and `member variable` accessing/modification if `A` is disabled.  This can be done by `overriding` `OnGetValue` and `OnSetValue`.  Just like above, one will need to exclude any `boolean` variables present in `SecondAttribute` that reside in `A`.